# How should I remove the number from my house?

Tags: walls, outdoor

The sign appears to be stuck to the outside. No screws. What is the best way to remove it?

[image: house number]

Comment: Check to make sure no screws behind the numbers.

Comment: Dynamite.  Or maybe a jackhammer.  (Seriously, if there are no visible fasteners then the odds are that the thing is glued to the wall.  Will be hard to remove without causing significant damage to the stucco finish.   But you might try prying the numbers out of the frame to see if there are any fasteners behind, and you might try running a hacksaw blade behind it.)

Comment: Tap up from the bottom in case it's wedged via keyhole slots on screws. If you see a bit of movement and it gets looser, keep going, if not, stop and try some other way.

Comment: You might try thin braided string, sawing back and forth. Just keep the string moving. (Second person is helpful for this.)

Comment: There could also be screws behind the tiles. If you don't mind ruining it, pry the tiles off and see.

Comment: I agree that it is likely there are screws behind the tiles. Here's a somewhat similar product and the comments indicate that the frame is mounted with screws and then the tiles are attached (with double-stick tape): https://www.wayfair.com/outdoor/pdp/nach-victoria-1-line-wall-address-plaque-w000476269.html

Comment: If you succeed in removing it without damage then I hope you plan on putting a bigger plaque to cover up the inevitable silhouette left behind by the current one.

Comment: @HotLicks  you, me, and MythBusters agree!